# SwiftUI truncate content of ForEach

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, hstack, swiftui-layout

In the following code snippet, the red circles obviously don't fit onto the screen and therefore only the trailing part of the HStack is shown. Instead of that behavior, I want the leading text of the HStack to always be visible and truncate the trailing red circles that don't fit into the available space (replaced with ...).
How can I do this?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("This text should always be visible")
                .layoutPriority(1)
            Spacer()
            ForEach(0..<20) { index in
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I want this:
[image]
instead of this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can get everything except the ellipses with:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Text("This text should always be visible")
        .fixedSize()
      ForEach(0..<20) { index in
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
          .font(.body)
          .foregroundColor(.red)
      }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
  }
}
```

In order to get the ellipses you'll probably have to calculate frame sizes or try to get your images into an attributed string which could get pretty complicated. You might also consider a scroll view or grid.